I'm trying to separate what the employee and admin can see on one datagridview table, it doesnt seem to work?
private void PopulateDataGridView()
{
    statusChecker(this.id);
    string query = "";
    DataBase connection = new DataBase();
    {
        connection.OpenSQLConnection();
        if (this.status == "Admin")
        {
            query = "SELECT AccountId,FullName,Attendance,Date FROM attendance";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "SELECT AccountId,FullName,Attendance,Date FROM attendance WHERE AccountId = @account";
        }
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection.mySqlConnection))
            {
                if (this.status == "Employee")
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", this.id);
                    MessageBox.Show(query);
                }
                using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

this is my code and it just displays all of the data in the database, why could this be? id is already ensured to be correct, i want it to display the specific employee's attendance if they will log-in.
I tried looking for a solution online but none has worked, i also tried to display a messagebox to check for the SQL statement, it is correct, I dont know why the display on the datagridview table is wrong?

It appears that this line determines what gets displayed: if (this.status == "Admin"). We don't know the type of this, nor do we know how this.status gets set. As a result there isn't much we can do from here. What do you see when you debug this? Oh, and what are the possible values for this.status beyond "Admin" and "Employee"? Have you considered using an enum rather than a strung for status

The status part already works, that is also used to display in a textbox what the user's status is, which displays whether they are an admin or an employee. I also checked which if statement runs by showing a message box that showed the query being used. all of this, yet the display is way off?
